# Which model can I apply, confused between applying models

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction

Below are the 3 columns I have in my data-set can anyone guide me on applying any models for the below.
So I would probably want to **predict region based on country and variety column**.
I am completely new towards this and would appreciate if someone could suggest me or guide me on applying model's

```
 col1(country)   col2(variety)             col3(region)
 Argentina       Chasselas                   r1 
 Israel          Gamay                       r2
 Mexico          Grenache                    r3
 Chile           Kalecik Karasi              r4
 China           Kallmet                     r5
```

I am trying something known as DecisionTreeClassifier, but would be happy if someone gives me other ideas over this

Comment: I hardly think a regressor is what you should be using for a classification task. Look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, so which column should I use here to train my model ? A little brief answer from your end would help me please

Comment: I don't know, what is r1 and r2? Classes or numbers?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably, I consider a multiple logistic regression as possible tool since you deal with a nominal dependent variable for this.

Basically, a (simple) linear regression is an algorithm, which predicts a continuous value; a logistic regression is considered as a binary classifier algorithm, which outputs the 'probability' of the input belonging to a label (0 or 1).

> Use multiple logistic regression when you have one **nominal variable**
>   and two or more measurement variables, and you want to know how the
>   measurement variables affect the nominal variable. You can use it to
>   predict probabilities of the dependent nominal variable, or if you're
>   careful, you can use it for suggestions about which independent
>   variables have a major effect on the dependent variable. Ref [Handbook of Biological Statistics](http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplelogistic.html).

Comment: is it known as multinomial regression ?

Comment: Right, a logistic regression can be applied to nominal or ordinal values. You are after a nominal.